# How can I arrange my divs in 2 columns so it looks like a grid/photo gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to coding and web design. Right now, I am constructing a portfolio website which showcases the other websites I've created. I am trying to create a layout where my Divs on the site are in two columns (under 'my work'). I am trying to figure out what to use but I'm unsure if I'm being honest. I've played around with display flex and display grid but I did not get the result I wanted. Here is my below... I will also link another persons' site to give you a visual of what I'm trying to achieve. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated... Thank you!

Also, I will include my code.

[My page and work so far](https://codepen.io/dechirila19/full/LYbLgOe)

[What I'm trying to create](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/zNBOYG)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 370px;
  padding-bottom: 370px;
 
  background-color: rgb(38,61,66);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New',       monospace;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.main-body {
  background-color: rgb(244,132,95);
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main-body2 {
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  
}

#tribute {
  width: 100%;
  
}

#product {
  width: 100%;
}

#survey {
  width: 100%;
}

#technical {
  width: 100%;
}

.work {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  
 
}

.work:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(38,61,66);
}

.desc {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
</div><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome To My Portfolio</h1>
<main>
  <div class="main-body">
 
  <h2>Some of my work</h2>
    
 <div class="main-body2">
   <div class="work">
<a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/dechirila19/full/poEOXVz">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/P8cbTC4Y-l-4nwkjTh3S67d5qHCvRMX7XyE6cXAsbTg4IX1AvB9-xEHexWDOK1q5YidvZtxXLo4TzjqLd3n21kJM8j_3xr_a5aZM3UyX3GrCg_0C--3zujKK-AL7TEyJxbmyJaRv16NvcTR6-B1y-P03TcvNtp11zB3tHYEtvf5TrwZJtInwwE0l_BkhUR-0OKuQO4O2RZZY0zeoo0Mrq7fd4i5rjf3HWb0yJ4WAC3TQP8w1vW0XdarfZZeBtfvnZny9BAEfYqIoUw9Rp9hcXp5Se4zkRs4TaJmJmRwOiWb44RjvNCJ4-oYTGfJZ9R2vL21eUEO28G0TexVTkhHxeB4c4APGteu-iNAB6jx-xUZa37WATiDPylYTtUS4vBU5tbFgvxu9Lvfb4mwVJN8gG6CzuKHou80TJS0yEgxQI6tOZrunP1DtIOAKgXgbGtGqLe6bK8YxYc5yYBH9a5mbp3eA2k50Rrh3Uh7YXpl02GmaPI05fak2wGJ0o0lyWgo0rNd6H0w3bpC91Anqvv_hTVnI1drISA5n8bCfY1m8UNM827qozZQh9Q7CUXOjf_Vkh2NunlyGiKtksT94gtCk59_HfDeBiNb-FPFlKjcRnxS9OyGAQdHFGWgrs5i40KOUKqsEyxY-2zujyECMZidTp4Vvi7mRRsiUMVPAdEkWyLO462xkFUiYVN5_hKOXlQ=s571-no?authuser=0" alt="Tribute Page" id="tribute">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Tribute Page</div>
      
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="main-body2">
   <div class="work">
<a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/dechirila19/full/VwKgmBg">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IJaG-M-uOIMWYyrEv1yOZRtlRmTV8diJY-d6DmFxyVJt2BE2-iXsRwFH1G21cOJgDBJCbjAZdvEG01gOTixgkZGmxaRbdlRqvaaVUI0wggikKtB8sGXa6irKIe3B3VB2apWyNghvYGEC0IoCCJgCskOP9x1Bs6wJAUSPONZa1maJrkOBYL_T3PPlfj5Jym_mj9hiuCAKYTMM_rV3ErLk94DJk3bSj2_ppQfo0meoZ_abrk7M81bB171SdDEKQ-q4MKf5SNQkZpZ4Xt-DWYINMbKe6ify9a_9jnAytdJxtcsDGzymzCAfTsW9Oo1QKuRVcp_fZmlKuL8ddJ2TPoYjW4UgwdU6Zt2Qya4Q2NvWcjUSsuScgChbtrqPFUDRuKAwkKD3YAdjAozXQxgGWHqKIR9Uvfd50NYGJRspzXm9t4HNmTHnknO3Alq80HUPVvXuxM3v6rtbfmj8k5__o5YXh7yAUBhO2WYRJxx3255laQXIPxXzXt9013nUp35bKsHGHxL56m6fdADPtxAm1grkEcICHlIoOyNayX2c34pMpXwaJFajEODZ4Le7ng0K7_ORv0CnfFM4Z4tEuw5B1DSK17UpPsRn2NFjPLSkI9BqCA-7ZL_DSlYZYwba7A4PyDbIXHstNzHjKuFPhmb3seCfVYkzMj4mOeGGzHwtL-P9ABTK9ImvZ4l4ILFgGMomXw=w567-h568-no?authuser=0" id="survey">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Survey Form</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="main-body2">
   <div class="work">
<a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/dechirila19/full/oNzrYQZ">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/QkjpqBlrvlMgUdoK6qSnXAcaqSFAdsZEDwrEsl96CGa-QXQrSUOiuf87cQlnYw6ciaelPWkk6hffKoyys4rcWb24DzGId2g2mHUFE52N0toZ6RzIQlXogtYDyWk2YVdnKshfyU_uEmIZJXED_qQ-M4bJ-l22us9yhDOSOSprhEp1oQoB4tICP-d8VPetANQihYa018aa87ixwKu9IA1vRgeS1QEPNcs9MXl0mPaEYx7br_jZuT-DJ2Ae_revIXieopvH_s7Iw-p9kEbb0OzB8lbqThiwCXmDaF6RcfhEDhI_A-sRlnscG6sqCOMn2bPGkNoWbKLkd3KpFnknwFwGpyMX-E3Q4jiBAcbaiROV70WlzkkypOSRwHAZuwWDRwf9qlnAOx-hJ46kMryfuH4ONqh6pe2UMe5lzaEnBaKMYpFuzupAelufIxl2maSraO7LFVEhixhAPJF7ldSMbaFNhXjNEk93DnvxOQuTqLAsWYCBfmFxVCFzWF2hfOHmK2YW7kTI4wTdt66QaI_fbfKeBrKOdAQ3qozVbnpBWymdgXc0rPmn2NrJFoLt327yX0XlIhOdvN-u31koYN3ThSUmJpKI15Pid8ScF7JifzAat4mEJQxk_bDZvCSTQnTCYQQagTVOHfixcQZ-OHfUp5korzvdg4L9sjLVK66meA19KXNNeWDYc3iadl1LscknFQ=w572-h571-no?authuser=0" id="product">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Product Landing Page</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
<div class="main-body2">
   <div class="work">
<a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/dechirila19/full/RworweN"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_K_RWpOCQKs5GZYhQkoupmelGzWqrZmhnOJ9zcRpSMZfDDGF8Z9x6KzCA-DpZdYKoh-sXB4B8wjzGXKiOseSkreQwa-rLboJmonxq1Ea2OdNYTIx5Ztdx4ZdHBliSKlEVPDej1yp1VqT80FYpcpao4TOpaS2doyBPFHg-KSkHID-Rr1tPHc8waaA44DiCvDpFI8zbT2E1qP9KprXOl5Zl9oKyOFOTr102ZqWvnWi4PnxgsnNSwQ34qDvYJmVX1C1XdcC1Yf7GNHbNjJ_Elh612G3tC2Ool7ynQ9TWnttk5T9Ah0HKks1BctQolk8NFHNnOKXAu0i2qVrz7Bq7GbYMH2h96v_btud-dGaV05E8rKQ2bMDLIhZeSq4cTPyBvhkHru5L0FgRUNuajR45suoZgbNVtkllKv5PM7pKfXbpgxDtTikii6-y6OhpoAZC3sFkyX0tWQP93PbJIJdXBPLjE1zoUNgxLqE0J2TDmU0mTYl1QcumbP2_C1biY9Q4fRj6MYgwiULgcsgb1EICpUVnsPIRVlc_jeMa81zTfoF-GJ_cIChtE0jTQt6IrDWjW55FU8rICtOUyRRyVhfy81_tkXdObtmzlJ8w9ZJL7RCXjbeCbl4YW0lTBoEqygUZJwRDAYuJTBOm4FWJIBIhC__lI1OKrVEwelyWyugOPVjSiyEt_IXk-V78vb2KkiJ7g=w570-h571-no?authuser=0" id="technical">
  
</a>
   <div class="desc">Technical Documentation Page</div>
     
  </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

use display : flex :

warp the four divs in a big div with class flex-main.
and this is the css:(only the parts with changes)

```
  .main-body {
    background-color: rgb(244,132,95);
    width: 100%;
    
  }
  .flex-main{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .main-body2 {
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
```

that would work as you want.good luck!

Comment: I tried doing this just now... I used it on both the .main-body and .main-body2 classes and it did not work as I thought it would.

Comment: well it does work. you just need to add margins in order to make it 2 colums.

Comment: i editd the answer with all the code you need.

Comment: I apologize I did not see the code you embedded for whatever reason... thanks so much, I'm gonna try it now